# How to sort by month with MySQL CTE?

Tags: mysql

I want to sort my bar graph by month. I use `ORDER BY Month` but it didn't work at all. When I use the CTE the arrangement of the month name is shuffled. Can somebody help me with my problem?

```
 WITH orders AS (SELECT YEAR(tbl_date.date) AS Year,
 DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b') AS Month,
 COUNT(tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id) AS Total_Order, 
 SUM(IFNULL(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity,0)) AS Quantity, 
 IFNULL(tbl_supplier_medicine.price,0) AS Price, 
 IFNULL((tbl_supplier_medicine.price) * 
 SUM(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity),0) AS Total_Amount, 
 tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier 
 FROM tbl_date 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received ON tbl_purchase_received.date_received = 
 tbl_date.date 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received_details ON 
 tbl_purchase_received.purchase_received_id = 
 tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier_medicine ON tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id 
 = tbl_purchase_received_details.supplier_medicine_id 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier ON tbl_supplier.supplier_id = 
 tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_id 
 WHERE YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW())
 GROUP BY Month, tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id)
 SELECT Month, COALESCE(SUM(Quantity),0) AS Quantity, 
 COALESCE(SUM(Total_Amount),0) AS Total_Amount from orders 
 GROUP BY Month ORDER BY Month
```

```
Month  Quantity  Total_Amount
Apr    0         0
Aug    300       3200
Dec    0         0
Feb    0         0
Jan    0         0
Jul    0         0
Jun    0         0
Mar    0         0
May    0         0
Nov    0         0
Oct    0         0
Sep    0         0
```

Comment: This question does not provide a minimal reproducible example.  Please include sample data and show us what the problem is.

Comment: The months are sorted in alphabetic order (Apr, Aug, ...), since you are using `'%b'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows are sorted by `Month`, but in alphabetical order. If you want them to be sorted in numerical order, then you need a column with numeric month values. You can use

```
MONTH(tbl_date.date) as month_num
```

The full query could be:

```sql
WITH orders AS (
    SELECT
        YEAR(tbl_date.date) AS Year,
        DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b') AS Month,
        MONTH(tbl_date.date) as month_num,
        COUNT(tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id) AS Total_Order, 
        SUM(IFNULL(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity,0)) AS Quantity, 
        IFNULL(tbl_supplier_medicine.price,0) AS Price, 
        IFNULL((tbl_supplier_medicine.price) * 
        SUM(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity),0) AS Total_Amount, 
        tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier 
    FROM tbl_date 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received
        ON tbl_purchase_received.date_received = tbl_date.date 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received_details
        ON tbl_purchase_received.purchase_received_id = tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier_medicine
        ON tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = tbl_purchase_received_details.supplier_medicine_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier
        ON tbl_supplier.supplier_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_id 
    WHERE YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW())
    GROUP BY Month, month_num, tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id
)
SELECT 
    Month,
    COALESCE(SUM(Quantity),0) AS Quantity, 
    COALESCE(SUM(Total_Amount),0) AS Total_Amount
from orders 
GROUP BY Month, month_num
ORDER BY month_num
```

Note that `month_num` should also be included in the GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: this is so informative

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting by this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b')
```

which returns the month's name: `Jan`, `Feb` etc.
So you do an alphabetical sorting which is wrong.
Include in the select list another column which will return the year along with the month so you can use it to sort the results:

```
WITH orders AS (
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%Y%m') AS YearMonth, 
    DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b') AS Month,
    COUNT(tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id) AS Total_Order, 
    SUM(IFNULL(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity,0)) AS Quantity, 
    IFNULL(tbl_supplier_medicine.price,0) AS Price, 
    IFNULL((tbl_supplier_medicine.price) * 
    SUM(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity),0) AS Total_Amount, 
    tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier 
  FROM tbl_date LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received 
  ON tbl_purchase_received.date_received = tbl_date.date 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_purchase_received_details 
  ON tbl_purchase_received.purchase_received_id = tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier_medicine 
  ON tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = tbl_purchase_received_details.supplier_medicine_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier ON tbl_supplier.supplier_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_id 
  WHERE YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW())
  GROUP BY YearMonth, Month, tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id
)
SELECT 
  Month, 
  COALESCE(SUM(Quantity),0) AS Quantity, 
  COALESCE(SUM(Total_Amount),0) AS Total_Amount 
from orders 
GROUP BY YearMonth, Month 
ORDER BY YearMonth
```